# Permission denied on Samba share

Tags: server-message-block

I am trying to setup a simple samba share, but all I can get is "permission denied" (both in Windows and Linux). This is my share section:

```
[pdf]
        comment = PDFs
        browseable = yes
        guest only = yes
        path = /writeable/path
        writable = yes
        public = yes  
        valid users = somevaliduser
```

I can mount the share and read files that are in there, but there is no write access. The dir itself has `rwxrwxrwx` permissions.

And of course, the Samba logs are useless as ever.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, it was SELinux.

I had checked it before using `selinuxenabled`, which returned `0`, turns out, that [means SELinux is *enabled*](http://linux.die.net/man/8/selinuxenabled). (Who thinks of these things?).

The correct command to check it is `sestatus`, which told me it was enabled and enforcing.

Comment: Return 0 = No error, so yes, SELinux is enabled and all is fine. Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

`guest only` means that only guest connections are permitted. This is contradictory to specifying `valid users`.

Comment: I deleted that part, still no luck. I am in fact now using the `[public]` example from smb.conf, and that has the same issue.

Comment: Found it. It was SELinux.